# colorbox contact form not working in iOS

Tags: ios, iframe, colorbox, contact-form

I'm trying to create a colorbox contact form calling from iframe. Everything looks good except that every time I try to click on the text box, the entire window gets shifted and makes it very hard to use. I've read it on another forum that the code below could be the answer yet the problem didn't go away.

```
<meta name="viewport" content="height=1000% width=1000%" />
```

Is it a known issue with colorbox? Does anyone have any solution to this? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Shouldn't it be?

```
 <meta name="viewport" content="height=1000% width=1000%" />
```

I really don't have any experience with this, but i think the " should be placed at the end of the 1000%

Comment: yes, stupid me. It should be placed at the end of 1000% yet the problem still exists. Thanks for pointing it out though.